# Explain the jquery code

Tags: jquery

Please run me through what happens on execution of **[this code](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_toggleclass_func)** Basically looking at **toggleClass(function(n)**

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function(){
        $("li").toggleClass(function(n){
          return "listitem_" + n;
        });
      });
```

**[Complete code is here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_toggleclass_func)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It waits until all HTML elements are accessible from the DOM, which is necessary to reliably find the elements that are on the page. That usually means that the HTML code of the pages first must have loaded (but not necessarily the images). ([Documentation for `.ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/))
2. A function is bound to all `button` elements that runs when the button is clicked. (Documentation for [`jQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) and [`.click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/))
3. For each `li` element in the page, a function is called, which returns `listitem_0` for the first one found, `listitem_1` for the second, and so on. [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) will remove that named class from the element if it already has it, but if it does not already have it, it will add it.

Hence, the button acts as a "toggle switch" that most likely switches the list items between two visually distinct appearances (defined by the page's CSS code).

Comment: for each is due to togglclass

Answer (score 2):

Check the comments

```
// when dom is loaded
$(document).ready(function(){
    // on somebody clicks a button element
    $("button").click(function(){
        // change the class of li elements in the page
        $("li").toggleClass(function(n){
            // with a value depending on the number of li element in 
            // the array of li elements
            return "listitem_" + n;
        });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the class that is returned from the function provided to `toggleClass` will be added if it doesn't exist, and removed if it does exist.

The `n` parameter is the index of the element in the node list, so the first element would have a class of `"listitem_0"` and so on...

Answer (score 0):

when the element with the ID "button" is clicked
The class listitem_[0-9] is added or removed from any li element depending on if it does or does not already have that class.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(document).ready(function(){  // document load, ready to execute code
      $("button").click(function(){  // when all html elements that have a tag named 'button' is clicked
        $("li").toggleClass(function(n){ // change the class of all li elements in the page to the "listitem_" + the number of li elements on the page
          return "listitem_" + n; 
        }); 
      });
```